# Sub menu needs to fold away first and then the first menu following using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

please see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rabelais/t6qc4Lrd/1/

```
var $menu = $('#menu');

$menu .click(function () {
if ( $('#igna-1').css('display') != 'none' ) {
    $('#igna-1').slideToggle("fast", function() {
        $('#igna-2').animate({ left: 'hide' }, 300, function() {
            $('#black, #igna, #dazed, #sons, #mad, #stimp').slideUp("fast", function() {
                $('#fatal').animate({ left: 'hide' }, 300);
            });
        });   
    });
} else if ( $('#fatal').css('display') == 'none' ) {
    $('#fatal').animate({ left: 'toggle' }, 300, function() {
        $('#igna, #black, #dazed, #sons, #mad, #stimp').slideToggle("fast");   
    });

} else {
    $('#black, #igna, #dazed, #sons, #mad, #stimp').slideUp("fast", function() {
        $('#fatal').animate({ left: 'hide' }, 300);
    });
}
if ($('#bio-line-1').css('display') != 'none') {
    $('#bio-line-2').slideUp("slow");

    window.setTimeout(function () {
        $('#bio-line-1').animate({ width: 'hide' });
    }, 300);
}
else if ( $('#mad-1').css('display') != 'none' ) {
    $('#mad-1, #mad-2, #mad-3').slideToggle("fast", function() {
        $('#mad-4').animate({ left: 'hide' }, 300, function() {
            $('#black, #igna, #dazed, #sons, #mad, #stimp').slideUp("fast", function() {
                $('#fatal').animate({ left: 'hide' }, 300);
            });
        });   
    });
}
```

1.Clicking on the WORK link opens further links.

2.Clicking on MAD LONDON opens a sub menu.

3.With both these menus open when you click on WORK again, both menus close at the same time.

My Question: Instead of them closing together I need the sub menu to fold away first and then the first menu. This affect does happen when one selects any link from the sub menu.

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's closed by the last `else` of your first `if` group, simply removing that last else will solve the problem (and in the example doesn't cause any other). See the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ktn425c6/

Comment: Thanks so much. However I just noticed that when the first menu is open on its own and you click on the work link again it doesn't close. Is there any chance you can sow me how to fix that again?

Comment: Right, so the solution is something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ktn425c6/1/ Practically checks if the mad is opened and only closes work directly if not, but this way the code is a bit redundant, you could easily optimize it, but since it's working I let you figure it out.